# colors in dash (not bash)

Tags: bash, dash-shell

In bash, you can colorize output with (for example)

```
echo -e "\e[34mblue text\e[0m"
```

But that does not work with dash.

Is there a way to get colored output with dash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With dash, bash, ksh, fish and zsh:

```
printf '%b' "\033[34;1mblue text\033[0m\n"
```

Comment: Or you could use `tput` and avoid the issue altogether: 'echo "$(tput setaf 4)blue text$(tput sgr0)"` or equivalent with `printf`